# Insert in 1st table and Update record in 2nd table using single query (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables table1 and table2.

Table 1, which have id and cardId as columns
and
Table 2, have cardId and UserId as columns

I want a single query which will insert record in table1 then update UserId in table2 base on cardId

Comment: Your question is both vague and too broad, but what you are looking for is `merge`:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.

Comment: Let me explain more
For example, I have two tables
Table 1, which have id and cardId as columns
and
Table 2, have cardId and UserId columns

I want a single query which will insert record in table1 then update UserId in table table2 base on cardId

Comment: What do you want to update UserId in Table2 to?  What do you meant by single query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I'm not familiar with merge.  Does it allow you to insert into one table and also update a different table?

Comment: Use two statements in a transaction so they appear atomic to anything else using the database.

Comment: Maybe you want to update UserId based on CardId?

Answer (score 0):

While defining your tables, `cardId` in `table1` should act as a primary key for `cardId` in `table2`. So, when you are creating `table1` and `table2` (assuming everything is of interger type), it should look as follows

```
Create table Table1
(id int,
cardId int primary key)

Create table Table2
(CardId int foreign key references table1(cardId) on update cascade,
UserId int)
```

You can see, I have used `on update cascade` with `cardId` in `table2`. In this way, when ever you update a certain value of `cardId` in `table1`, it will automatically be updated in `table2`
For example, this following statement will change `cardId` in `table1` and automatically in `table2` from 30 to 32.

```
Update table1 set cardId=30 where cardId=32
```

Although, above statement tries to update `cardId` only in `table1` but since we have used `on update cascade` while defining `cardId` in `table2`, `cardId` in `table2` will automatically be updated.
Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, if you use procedures in sql-server. You can create a procedure with multi query SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE... After you only exec a time, it will run all your query.
You can reseach procedures in: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_stored_procedures.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a trigger that would update the row in the second table when an insert occurs in the first table. Since it's not clear what the userId in the second column has to be set to the below trigger uses the USER() function and can be changed as needed.

Data setup

```
Insert into Table2 (cardId, userId) values (1,null)
```

Trigger

```
Create trigger update_user after insert on Table1
For each row
Update Table2 set userId = USER() WHERE cardId = NEW.cardId
```

Test Data

```
Insert into Table1 (id, cardId) values(1,1)
```

On executing the test data insert above, the `userId` column in `Table2` will get set to the `userId` returned by the `USER()` function